# How to display url - inside of onclick event - Jquery Append Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to upload image and display uploaded image using jquery append method. In this method i need to add onclick event to the respective image tag.

First i create one javascript variable and assign image path. In image src attribute i define js variable its display correct, but onclick event its display wrong. i display below.

```
<img src="http://localhost/farhuman/media/com_farhuman/uploads/12102019105542fb9e03695b663514a7bce87e5ff9180bdiwali.png" onclick="addclipart(" http:="" localhost="" farhuman="" media="" com_farhuman="" uploads="" 12102019105542fb9e03695b663514a7bce87e5ff9180bdiwali.png')'="">
```

here is my append script

```
var imagepaths="<?php echo JUri::base(); ?>media/com_farhuman/uploads/"+json['code'];

$("#uploadedimgs").append("<div class='col-md-4'><img src='"+imagepaths+"' onClick='addclipart('"+imagepaths+"')'></div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `backticks` to eliminate minor syntax error. Also, keep in mind the path variable should be passed as a string.

```js
let imagepaths = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_250,h_250,c_mfit/w_700/sample.jpg';
$("#uploadedimgs").append(`
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="${imagepaths}" onClick="addclipart('${imagepaths}')" /></div>
`);

function addclipart(path) {
  console.log(path)
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="uploadedimgs"></div>
```